# Impose a lone attribute to be empty in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I was wondering if there's a way, in a fact, to force an attribute of a signature be empty.  I tried this way but it seems not work:

```
sig C {
 myattribute: lone Type
}
```

sig Type {
     att1: Int
     att2: ..... etc..
    }

```
fact {
    all c: C| 
        (my condition) 
        <=>
        (
            no c.myattribute
        )
}
```

As for now we can just think about defing a structure with an abstract signature this way:

```
abstract sig GeneralType {}
one sig Empty extends GeneralType {}
sig NotEmpty extends GeneralType {...arguments (att1,2....}
```

Comment: Actually, your code should work as it is. Maybe there is something unexpected going on with "my condition"? Try  tor replace "my condition" with something like "1=1" for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing code should already work given the right `my condition`. (wmeyer is indeed correct in suggesting that.)

You can test your constraint to make sure it is behaving as you would expect:

```
sig Type { }

sig C {
    myattribute: lone Type
}

fact {
    all c: C | no c.myattribute
}

run { } for 5

check {
    all c: C | no c.myattribute
} for 5
```